# Custom command expands counter again

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, fmtcount

I am trying to create two custom commands, that create subsections with labels and custom numbering. But when I use `\nameref` to get the title of the
reference, it expands `\decimal{reqCounter}` again so that the numbering does not fit to the label anymore.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Define requirement command
\newcounter{reqCounter}
\setcounter{reqCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\requirement}[3] {
  \subsection*{RQ\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{reqCounter}}: #2}
  \label{req:#1}
  \refstepcounter{reqCounter}
#3
}

% Define testcase command
\newcounter{tcCounter}
\setcounter{tcCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\testcase}[5] {
  \subsection*{TC\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tcCounter}}: #3}
  \label{tc:#1}
  \refstepcounter{tcCounter}
#4

#5

Covers: \nameref{#2}
}

\begin{document}


\requirement{timer}
  {Timer}
  {
    It shall be possible to use the system timer for task scheduling purposes.
  }

\testcase{timer-simple}{req:timer}
  {Timer simple}
  {
    Enable the system timer and enable/disable a LED in a 60Hz interval.
  }
  {
    Verify the frequency with an oscilloscope or a digital signal analyser.
  }

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled MWE]

In this example, the text after "Covers:" should show "RQ01: Timer" and not "RQ02: Timer". This tells me, that tex is expanding that subsection title again, so that the current counter value is used, instead of just displaying the constructed subsection title. Can you tell me, what is the correct way of doing such a thing?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more what you are trying to do here. I do not understand your macros here. You use `\section*` and `\refstepcounter` **after** the label, so what exactly are you expecting `req:timer` to actually return. If I move the two `\refstepcounter`'s up above the `\section*`'s and let the counter start from zero, I seem to get what you are look for?

Comment: And please document your macro arguments!  #1 #2 and #3 do not in themselves give any indication what they are used for.

Comment: @daleif: The shifting of the `\refstepcounter` does solve the numbering problem only for a short 'moment', since the content of `\decimal{reqCounter}` is written unexpanded to the `.aux` file, so having more than one those  `\requirement` macros, `\nameref` will use the current counter value and not the one being valid at the time of `\requirement` usage. (the same holds for the `testcase` macro usage)

Comment: @daleif: It was my first idea as well, then I saw your comment and tried it and it did not work in sense of 'providing the correct reference value'. I suspected the unexpanded storage then and checked the `.aux` file. The 4th argument of `\newlabel` has `\decimal{reqCounter}` inside, i.e. unexpanded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `\refstepcounter` is used too late, especially it's done after `\label`, which is useless
2. `\nameref` uses the `4th` argument of the `\newlabel` content written to the `.aux` file. However, this is an unexpanded `\decimal{reqCounter}`, so at the time of `\nameref` usage, it will grab the current value of `reqCounter` and not the expanded ('frozen') one.

A possible solution for both is to shift the `\refstepcounter{...}\label{...}` macros upward and explicitly define an expanded `\@currentlabelname` which is written to the `.aux` file instead of the unexpanded `\decimal{reqCounter}`.

---

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Define requirement command
\newcounter{reqCounter}
\newcounter{tcCounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\requirement}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \refstepcounter{reqCounter}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{RQ\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{reqCounter}}: #2}
  \label{req:#1}
  \subsection*{RQ\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{reqCounter}}: #2}%
  \endgroup
#3
}

% Define testcase command
\newcommand{\testcase}[5]{%
  \refstepcounter{tcCounter}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{TC\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tcCounter}}: #3}
  \label{tc:#1}
  \subsection*{TC\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tcCounter}}: #3}
  #4%

  #5%

  Covers: \nameref{#2}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\requirement{timer}
  {Timer}
  {
    It shall be possible to use the system timer for task scheduling purposes. See \nameref{tc:timer-simple}
  }


\requirement{othertimer}
  {Other Timer}
  {
    It shall be possible to use the system timer for task scheduling purposes. See \nameref{tc:othertimer-simple}
  }



\testcase{timer-simple}{req:timer}
{Timer simple}
{
  Enable the system timer and enable/disable a LED in a 60Hz interval.
}
{
  Verify the frequency with an oscilloscope or a digital signal analyser.
}

\testcase{othertimer-simple}{req:othertimer}
{Other timer simple}
{
  Enable the system timer and enable/disable a LED in a 60Hz interval.
}
{
  Verify the frequency with an oscilloscope or a digital signal analyser.
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even shorter, but possibly errorprone: `\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{\@currentlabelname}\label{...}` after the `\subsection` usage

Comment: This does the trick. Thanks (I still need to learn a lot about the tex backend)

Comment: @FlorinHillebrand: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!